How to get a movie without acceleration with OpenCV?
I try to program a detection camera with firmata in Python. When the PIR sensor detects motion, my logitech C920 usb webcam starts recording a sequence of 10 seconds. All is good, but I realized that the sequence recorded by my webcam is about 6 seconds instead of 10 seconds. It turns out, that the sequence has been accelerated.
I would like to obtain a movies of 10 seconds in 1080x720 30 fps (my webcam resolution)
Here is my code:
import pyfirmata
import time
import cv2
import os

# Configurer la connexion avec la carte Arduino (modifie 'COM3' selon ton port)
board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM3')

# Configurer la broche pour le capteur PIR (broche 7)
pir_pin = board.get_pin('d:7:i')  # 'd' pour digital, '7' pour la broche, 'i' pour input

# Configurer la broche pour la LED intégrée (broche 13)
led_pin = board.get_pin('d:13:o')  # 'd' pour digital, '13' pour la broche, 'o' pour output

# Démarrer l'itérateur pyFirmata pour s'assurer que les lectures sont mises à jour correctement
it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

# Configuration de la capture vidéo avec OpenCV
def record_video(duration=10):
    desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
    video_filename = os.path.join(desktop_path, 'video_output.mp4')

    # Ouvrir la webcam
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

    # Obtenir les propriétés de la vidéo (largeur, hauteur)
    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
    fps = 30  # Frames per second

    # Définir le codec et créer l'objet VideoWriter pour enregistrer la vidéo en MP4
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_filename, fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

    # Capturer la vidéo pendant `duration` secondes
    start_time = time.time()
    while int(time.time() - start_time) < duration:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            # Écrire le cadre dans le fichier vidéo
            out.write(frame)

            # Afficher la vidéo en cours de capture (optionnel)
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

            # Arrêter si l'utilisateur appuie sur 'q'
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

    # Libérer la webcam et fermer les fenêtres
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    print(f"Vidéo enregistrée sous : {video_filename}")

# Fonction principale pour vérifier le capteur PIR et déclencher l'enregistrement vidéo
print("Test du capteur PIR démarré...")

while True:
    pir_value = pir_pin.read()  # Lire l'état du capteur PIR (valeurs: True/False ou None)

    if pir_value is not None:   # Si on a bien une lecture valide
        if pir_value:           # Si mouvement détecté (pir_value == True)
            print("Mouvement détecté !")
            led_pin.write(1)    # Allumer la LED
            record_video(10)    # Enregistrer une vidéo pendant 10 secondes
        else:
            print("Aucun mouvement")
            led_pin.write(0)    # Éteindre la LED

    time.sleep(1)  # Pause d'une seconde entre chaque vérification

I tried to change the codec Xvid H624 AVI etc., but nothing else changed. With this code, setting cap.get(3) etc. the movies have a 640x480 resolution. My webcam resolution is 1080x720 30 fps and when I change this resolution, a movie is recorded but won't play.
How can I obtain a 10 second movie with a resolution of 1080x720 at 30 FPS?

Hello !
I'm not an expert in OpenCV, but cap.read() is reading the current image coming from your camera, and here, you are recording faster than the camera FPS.
But honestly, it should be the opposite, you should have a clip longer that 10 seconds then.
Can you check how many times ret is set to false in a count ? Maybe it skips some frames because you are accessing the driver too fast ?

"cap.get(3)" -- sigh, gotta love those magic numbers. Use the VideoCaptureProperties enum, it's much more legible.

Problem is that you just claim it's 30FPS, but then just have a free-running loop (including synchronous visualization and cv2.waitKey, which will waste a significant amount of time). And if "sequence has been accelerated", it means the code is already running slower than 30 frames per second and can't keep up.

[mre] required. I see "firmata". strip that. strip everything that doesn't belong.

potentially the camera isn't giving you 30 fps. use cap.get() with CAP_PROP_FPS to see what the camera claims it will give you

@DanMašek I tried your solution to cut cv2.waitKey and it works : the video is about 10 secondes with a resolution of 640x480. After this, I tried to apply the answer of bardiaarman to get my video with 1080x720 resolution but again the video is accelerated (4 seconds sequence) but the resolution is good ! Someone guess what's the problem, I'm lost lol

You're still encoding the video synchronously with the capture, and the computer can't keep up now that you've got a larger amount of data. The 300 frames at 1080x720 will only take about 700 MiB raw, so you could just capture first, and only then do the encoding. (Of course, that approach won't work if you want to record a longer clip)

Your processing is too slow or your camera doesn't provide the fps that you have chosen for the writer. One general reliable way is to first record the images either to a buffer (if enough ram) or to s file and also create timestamps for the images (e.g. when you receive them), then anslyze the real fps (and/or fill gaps with duplicates of images) and then craate another writer with the correct fps and write everything again. Mind that this is a huge overhead.

@Micka hello, ty for your answer, I tried your solution. It shows that my camera provide real 15 fps (and so if I want a movies of 10 seconds, every frame is duplicate to complete the missing frames). I don't understand why my camera provide 15 fps while in the datasheet it says 1080x720 30 fps. (my "camera" is a webcam usb logitech C920).

OpenCV tries to set its own defaults. you can override them by setting the CAP_PROPs. mind that the C920 needs FOURCC MJPG set as well, or else you won't achieve that frame rate and frame size. setting it works only in a specific order. try setting it first, and if that doesn't work, set it last.

cv2.VideoCapture() might not automatically set the correct resolution.
you can try this to manually set the resolution of the webcam to 1280x720 (which is equivalent to 1080p HD)
def record_video(duration=10):
    desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 
    'Desktop')
    video_filename = os.path.join(desktop_path, 'video_output.mp4')      
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    # manually set the resolution of webcam
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)  
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)  
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)            
    frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_filename, fourcc, 30, (frame_width, 
    frame_height))
    start_time = time.time()


1280x720 is not equivalent to 1080p

OP already uses the capture's size to initialize the writer (cap.get calls). a different frame size doesn't affect the outcome.

thanks for your correction , Writing error, which it is 1920x1080.

could you reproduce OP's issue at all?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
